# Segmentation Error in C programming

Tags: c

I am trying to compile a program in C, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Segmentation fault
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define calculation1 main
void calculation1(int *num1, int *num2) {

        int total;

        printf("Program One: \n");
        printf("=========== \n");

        printf("Number One: ");
        scanf("%d", &num1);

        printf("Number Two: ");
        scanf("%d", &num2);

        total = *num1 + *num2;

        printf("%d + %d = %d \n",&num1,&num2,total );
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix this error?

Comment: '&' is the "address of" operator, you've already passed addresses to the function so you shouldn't be passing the address of the addresses to your scanf calls.  scanf takes the address of the variable you want it to store the result in.

Comment: What is this : `#define calculation1 main` ??

Comment: "My code segfaults" is not a **specific** problem description. Learn using a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix this error?

**Problem 1**

By using

```
#define calculation1 main
void calculation1(int *num1, int *num2) {
```

you are essentially using:

```
void main(int *num1, int *num2) {
```

This is wrong. `main` needs to be:

```
int main(void) {
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
```

Your program is subject to undefined behavior.

**Problem 1**

You are using

```
scanf("%d", &num1);
scanf("%d", &num2);
```

when `num1` and `num2` are of type `int*`. Thy need to be:

```
scanf("%d", num1);
scanf("%d", num2);
```

**Problem 3**

You are using

```
    printf("%d + %d = %d \n",&num1,&num2,total );
```

Given the type of `num1` and `num2`, that needs to be:

```
    printf("%d + %d = %d \n", *num1, *num2, total );
```

**Fix**

Your program needs a bit of an overhaul. Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define calculation1 main
int calculation1() {

   int num1; // Not int*. If you use int*, you'll need to allocate memory
   int num2;

   int total;

   printf("Program One: \n");
   printf("=========== \n");

   printf("Number One: ");
   scanf("%d", &num1);  // You need to use &num1 since num1 is of type int.

   printf("Number Two: ");
   scanf("%d", &num2);

   total = num1 + num2;

   printf("%d + %d = %d \n", num1, num2, total);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @jayant, It's fixed.

Comment: int main(){} or int main(void){}?

Comment: @Michi, `main(void)` is definitely better than `main()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%d", num1);
scanf("%d", num2);
```

scanf needs an address and num1 and num2 already contain the address as you pass them as pointers in the function.

The other thing to change is:

```
printf("%d + %d = %d \n",*num1,*num2,total );
```

`*num1` dereferences a pointer to provide the value

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I still get the error and why do we need to remove & from scanf()?

Comment: @HassenFatima How do you call function ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with another mistake that I noticed in your code. And yes it would be interesting to see how you call your function.

Answer (score 1):

Despite errors pointed by @jayant-

```
#define calculation1 main
void calculation1(int *num1, int *num2) {
```

So , `calculation1` will be replaced by `main` ,so in short this is your `main` function .

This is not a valid and should avoid it any case . I am confused how you make a call or take command line argument ? But this is definitely incorrect .

Simply,do this -

`int main(void)` or `int main(int argc,char *argv[])` and declare `num1` and `num2` as `int` variables and then take input in it and perform desired operation.